# why String.format("%02x ", -1) return ffffffff instead of ff?

Tags: java, hex, string.format

I need to convert byte to hex string, and tried below: 
    String.format("%02x", -1);

Note, -1 here is two's complement integer

However the return I get is "ffffffff" instead of "ff" which is expected?

Comment: Because `ff` isn't `-1`. It's 255. Specifying `02` in your format might pad a short number with a leading zero to get it up to 2 digits, but it won't shorten a number in a way that would give the wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting *does not truncate* any significant digits. That's why if you specify less positions than needed for representation, your limit will be ignored and all significant digits will be represented. For instance, if you have a number 0x12345 and try to format it using only 2 positions (like in your format), the result string will consist of 5 digits, not 2.

Hexadecimal ff means decimal 255, not decimal -1 as you may have expected. The number -1 is of type *int*. It takes 4 bytes in memory. Its hexadecimal representation really needs ffffffff, i.e. 8 hex digits. There are no leading zeroes that you could truncate. Leading zeroes are possible for positive numbers only. For instance, -2 will be formatted to fffffffe, -3 to fffffffd, -256 to ffffff00, -257 to fffffeff, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ff` isn't `-1`. It's 255. Specifying `02` in your format might **pad** a short number with a leading zero to get it up to 2 digits, but it won't truncate a number in a way that would give the wrong value.

If you want to get a one-byte value for a number, you can cut it to one byte with `&0xff`.

```
int n = -1;
String.format("%02x", n&0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `%02` means the **minimum** width of the result should be 2 and pad with `0` if needed. It does nothing if the result is more than 2 characters wide.

Knowing that, and the fact Java integers are 32 bits long, the result is expected. If you want `ff`, you can either do `String.format("%02x", 255)` or `String.format("%02x", (byte)-1)`.